# using scanner and delimiter to read text file into array list

Tags: java

i have some homework that needs me to read from a text file that uses ":" (colon) as a delimiter. the contents of the file are information about animals which include names, height and size and more. The text within the file contains floats, Integers and Strings however the main problem is when reading the file it takes in information from the next line this is because the final string which each line has does not end with a ":" but a full stop.

file:

```
Saltwater Crocodile:453:17:50:7:88:Crocodiles can slow their heartbeat down to two beats per minute.
Praying Mantis:0.02:0.22:41:5:39:They can turn their heads up to 180 degrees in search of insects.
```

i first put the text file into an arraylist using scanner called s.hasNext

when using delimiter 
s.useDelimiter("[:]");

the program would print out

"Their existence was unknown to humans until about 100 years ago.
Saltwater Crocodile"

instead of just "Their existence was unknown to humans until about 100 years ago." when called.

i have tried adding a full stop to the delimiter like this 
scan.useDelimiter("[:.]");
however when i do this it messes with the floats which also have "."

```
 try (
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(dataPath))) {

 s.useDelimiter("[:]");     

                ArrayList<String> animalArr = new ArrayList();
                while (s.hasNext()) {
                    animalArr.add(s.next());
              }

 System.out.println(animalArr.get(7));
```

> "Their existence was unknown to humans until about 100 years ago.
>   Saltwater Crocodile"

just not have the next line information be apart of the previous lines string.
ive been trying to figure this out for 2 days now please i need all the help i can get. mayb theres a way to ignore the full stop im sorry for my ineptitude.

System.out.println(animalArr.get(7));

"Their existence was unknown to humans until about 100 years ago.
Saltwater Crocodile"

to be

"Their existence was unknown to humans until about 100 years ago".
basically the tldr

Comment: Read the file line by line. Parse each line.

Comment: Two nested loops. In the outer loop, use BufferedReader.readLine. In the inner loop, use split on the ":" delimiter.

Comment: Where is the text "Their existence was unknown to humans until about 100 years ago" in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the delimiter to use ":" which tells the `.next()` method to find all text up to the ":". In your case, it's:

> "Their existence was unknown to humans until about 100 years ago. Saltwater Crocodile"

I would use `.hasNextLine()` and `.nextLine()` to get each line in the file (since each line has a hard stop). Then use `myLine.split(":")` to get each field in the line.

Comment: ty i was able to get each line into an array list which solved my problem!

Comment: @Panthera If your problem is solved please accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code resolves your problem:

```
try {
    ArrayList<String> animalArr = new ArrayList();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(dataPath));
    s.useDelimiter("[:]");  
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String txt = s.next();
        if(txt.contains(".") && !txt.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
            String txt1 = txt.substring(0, txt.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            String txt2 = txt.substring(txt.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, txt.length());
            animalArr.add(txt1.trim());
            animalArr.add(txt2.trim());
        } else {
            animalArr.add(txt);
        }
    }   
    for(String a : animalArr) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### Live example (with adaptation to show results without file):

- http://tpcg.io/2wmYQn